# Bcrypting sessions or cookies

Tags: php, encryption

Could you use Bcrypt to crypt a session or a cookie containing a password? I'm just curious really. For example you could create a function where it checks the stored bcrypted username, password to see if they match up to display a certain piece of data?

Comment: You should never store a password in a cookie, encrypted or not

Comment: Okay - To further my question then, how about using bcrypt to securely store a IP for a function to check against in MySql to see if a user is logged in?

Comment: What you're saying doesn't necessarily mean anything. You can "crypt" anything anytime you want, that doesn't mean that there's any point to it. You'd have to clarify what exactly you want to do for what purpose and what problem it solves.

Comment: If lets say I stored a IP into a cookie, would it be better to crypt it or not?

Comment: Why would you want to store an IP in a cookie?

Comment: I was just using it as an example.

Comment: Come up with a real world example then: yes you can, but your examples so far are pointless or downright insecure

Comment: Encryption is all about preventing certain parties from obtaining information that other parties can. In order for any sort of encryption to make sense, you first need to define a scenario with at least two parties which somehow transfer data and which of the two parties may access what data when. Without such a scenario talking about anything specific is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you **MAY NOT DO IT**.

- It is unnecessary to encrypt something that you store in sessions, because they are stored server-side.
- It is dumb to store a password in a cookie, encrypted or not.

Better options are

1. Store it as plain-text in a session
2. Store an unique key in a cookie, and store the unique key with the password on your server

Use bCrypt to store passwords. If you want to store something in the RAM or in a session, encryption is unnecessary.